# Balanced parentheses

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, stack, balanced-delimiters

> Given an expression string exp, write a program to examine whether the
>   pairs and the orders of
>
> ```
> "{","}","(",")","[","]"
> ```
>
> are correct in exp.
>
> For example, the program should print true for
>
> ```
> exp = "[()]{}{[()()]()}"
> ```
>
> and false for
>
> ```
> exp = "[(])"
> ```

Complexity:

- Time complexity: \$O(n)\$ where \$n\$ is length of string
- Space complexity: \$O(\frac{n}{2})\$ where \$n\$ is length of string

I saw the Java version and thought "I want to submit a JavaScript version." Looking for code review, optimizations, and best practices.

In my version, the string can contain other characters than parentheses, `""` is accepted as input, and I did not care about short circuiting odd length strings.

```
function parenthesesAreBalanced(s)
{
  var parentheses = "[]{}()",
    stack = [], //Parentheses stack
    i, //Index in the string
    c; //Character in the string

  for (i = 0; c = s[i++];)
  {
    var bracePosition = parentheses.indexOf(c),
      braceType;
    //~ is truthy for any number but -1
    if (!~bracePosition)
      continue;

    braceType = bracePosition % 2 ? 'closed' : 'open';

    if (braceType === 'closed')
    {
      //If there is no open parenthese at all, return false OR
      //if the opening parenthese does not match ( they should be neighbours )
      if (!stack.length || parentheses.indexOf(stack.pop()) != bracePosition - 1)
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
      stack.push(c);
    }
  }
  //If anything is left on the stack <- not balanced
  return !stack.length;
}

console.log('{}([]) true', parenthesesAreBalanced('{}([])'));
console.log('{{ false', parenthesesAreBalanced('{{'));
console.log('[(]) false', parenthesesAreBalanced('[(])'));
console.log("{}([]) true", parenthesesAreBalanced("{}([])"));
console.log("([}]) false", parenthesesAreBalanced("([}])"));
console.log("([]) true", parenthesesAreBalanced("([])"));
console.log("()[]{}[][]", parenthesesAreBalanced("()[]{}[][]"));
```

Comment: add this check as the first validation, If the length of the expression is an odd number we can return false right away.

Comment: @Ananda this supports non braces, "abc" and "o[]" are balanced and odd length

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is almost all style suggestions; the code itself looks great.

Personally, I prefer the brace-on-same-line style for everything in JS, and I prefer proper blocks instead of inlining expressions. But those are just preferences. I've also skipped the bitwise trick, added some strict comparisons instead of `!stack.length` etc., moved the `i++` over to its "usual" place, and lengthened a few variable names, just for clarity.

Again: This is all basically pointless, but I just like spelling things out.

The only real difference is that rather than push the opening brace onto the stack, I push the position of the expected closing brace. It just makes the conditional a bit cleaner later on.

```
function parenthesesAreBalanced(string) {
  var parentheses = "[]{}()",
    stack = [],
    i, character, bracePosition;

  for(i = 0; character = string[i]; i++) {
    bracePosition = parentheses.indexOf(character);

    if(bracePosition === -1) {
      continue;
    }

    if(bracePosition % 2 === 0) {
      stack.push(bracePosition + 1); // push next expected brace position
    } else {
      if(stack.length === 0 || stack.pop() !== bracePosition) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length === 0;
}
```

---

Update: Actually, you can skip one `stack.length` check in the inner conditional; `stack.pop()` will just return `undefined` if the stack's empty, so this is enough:

```
if(stack.pop() !== bracePosition) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I very much like the idea of pushing the `bracePosition+1`, +1

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a Node/JavaScript library called **[balanced](https://github.com/icodeforlove/node-balanced)** that can do this and much more, but the main concept I used was using a stack, compiling a regexp of the `open`/`close` tags, and then doing 1 pass. It seemed to perform better than `indexOf` implementations.

The way you would write your `isBalanced` method using balanced is

```
function isBalanced(string) {
    return !!balanced.matches({source: string, open: ['{', '(', '['], close: ['}', ')', ']'], balance: true});
}
```

Here's a live example with exceptions: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/3S4WR/)** and heres an example ignoring comment blocks **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/8ULvA/)**

For your example `balanced` will produce the following error

```
Balanced: mismatching close bracket, expected ")" but found "]" at 1:3

1: [(])
-----^
```

Comment: I like your answer. But, there are some glitches. I think you should improve it and make it better to parse whole JS function or FILE. 
For example: On your JS fiddle i pasted a JS line containing .replace(/[{]/g, "").replace(/[}]/g, "") . And it failed.